# SQL - Insert form into a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a php script to insert form input into a database called XXXX_comments into the Table called Comments that has Name and Comment as columns.When a user hits Save button the form should be inserted into the DB. I connect to the database using connect.php :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$Dbconnect = "XXX_comments";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($conn,$Dbconnect);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

in my index.php file i have the following form:

```
<?php
    include ('connect.php');
?>

<?php               
        if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Comments (Name, Comment) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $comment);
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $comment = $POST['comment'];
        $stmt->execute();  
        Echo "Succefully inserted to table";
 }
 ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="post-review-box" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form id="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form-control animated" id="firstname" type="hidden" placeholder="Enter your Name">
        <br>
        <input id="ratings-hidden" name="rating" type="hidden">
        <textarea class="form-control animated" cols="50" id="comment" placeholder="Enter your review here..." rows="5"></textarea>
        <br>
        <div class="text-right">
          <div class="stars starrr" data-rating="0"></div>
          <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="#" id="close-review-box" style="display:none; margin-right: 10px;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</a>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit" name="Save">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="display"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The connection is successful but the data is not being inserted.

Comment: You're trying to insert 3 values into 2 columns, with only 2 parameters.

Comment: Sorry that was a Typo i updated the answer, It still doesnt insert the data.

Comment: change this line also  $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $comment);

Comment: Try checking for [errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) instead of blindly assuming that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one intrested I have solved the issue, It seemed like the submit button wasn't responding So i added a javascript onclick function to force submit the form.

```
<input class="btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
</script>
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign values before you can use them as below code:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Comments (Name, Comment) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $comment);
```

Comment: It is the same no data has been inserted

Answer (score 1):

You should give name to your inputs and textarea inside the form as

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control animated" id="firstname" type="hidden" placeholder="Enter your Name">
<input id="ratings-hidden" name="rating" type="hidden">
<textarea class="form-control animated" cols="50" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Enter your review here..." rows="5"></textarea
```

and you are assigning values after the binding it to the query, you should assign values for `$firstname` and `$comment` before binding it to the query as

```
if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Comments (Name, Comment) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $comment);    
    $stmt->execute();  
    echo "Succefully inserted to table";
}
```

**Edit:** The code was using $POST instead of $_POST.

Comment: It is the same no data has been inserted

Comment: @WojtekT i have edited my ansewer, you forgot to assign name for your form elements(inputs and textarea)

Comment: Change all its still the same. Ill try some error checking

Comment: U can check the website here https://tadzik9634.000webhostapp.com/index.php

Answer (score 1):

**Few remarks**:

First of all, in the connect.php file you're mixing OOP and Procedural styles, you can gain the same result by using the following code:

```
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $Dbconnect);
```

Next, in your index.php, you've created a prepared statement, but you assigned that to $sql variable, and later you tried to use the undefined $stmt variable, so in order to fix that just change the first 2 lines

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Comments (Name, Comment) VALUES (?, ?)"); 
 $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $comment);
```

Hope it will solve your little issue!

Comment: No errors that's the problem ;/ u can check the website tadzik9634.000webhostapp.com/index.php

Comment: It doesn't help much as I can't see your database structure, can you add a screenshot of your database structure?

Comment: I cant upload any images all websites are blocked i will upload one in few hour

Comment: I ran This SQL COmmand to create it CREATE TABLE Comments (

    Name varchar(255),
    Comment text(800)
);

Comment: It would be better if we can see in some way your database structure, as the issue might be something small and silly, but as long as we can't see it, it is really hard to examine.